# SFDX force:mdapi:retrieve returns different result for scratch org and dev hub for translations metadata

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata-api, scratch-org, translation, translation-workbench

When running a `sfdx force:mdapi:retrieve` command on scratch org and dev hub, results returned are different in translation files even when my package.xml is same for both retrievals.

My Package.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>Label</members>
        <members>Label2</members>
        <name>CustomLabel</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Translations</name>
    </types>
    <version>47.0</version>
</Package>
```

Adding 2 labels, as i just want to retrieve translations for 2 labels.
Retrieved result from Scratch Org has all the org labels in translation file while same retrieval from dev hub returns the package file specified labels in translation file.

Thoughts on why this same retrieve command returns different results or is there a different way to retrieve metadata from scratch org?

Comment: Any reason you don't want to use the `sfdx force:source:retrieve`?  Source formatting is usually the defacto way to go for development these days

Comment: force:mdapi:retrieve returns the result in metadata format. Although, even after running force:source:retrieve,the returned results are same.